# Need to prove quantity/date of Ether Pre-Sale purchase for tax reasons

Tags: ether, presale

Lucky me - I bought 10000 Ether for 5BTC in the pre-sale and forgot about them until just recently. Yahoo! However, now that I've sold some at a profit I'm going to need to prove the date and quantity of purchase for the tax authorities and I'm not sure they'll just accept an email dated 2014. Even if they do the confirmation email doesn't state the quantity purchased. Idiot me updated all my BTC wallets since then without taking screenshots so the list of transactions no longer includes the transfer to the bitcoin address I used to purchase the Ether. Didn't realize that an update would wipe the transaction history to date but there you go.

Does the Ethereum Foundation provide any kind of proof-of-purchase for people who bought in the pre-sale? If I could only find proof of the quantity purchased then I would at least have a continuous 'chain' of proof [Press release stating quantity of Ether per BTC - purchase confirmation email - price of BTC on that date - ... quantity purchased...].

This is important as in Germany if I can prove I've held them longer than 1 year I won't have to pay tax. I would really appreciate some help!

Comment: It appears you have your address, why not just go to http://etherscan.io and print out all the transactions on that account?

Comment: Thank you - not a bad idea, and one i'll run with for the time being. However, I wonder if it will satisfy the tax authorities as it doesn't show the date on which the Ether was purchased, but rather the time between the moment of enquiry and, I guess, the genesis block. Also in a fomat that might be a little difficult for a tax bureaucrat to decipher. I thought I might get lucky with the foundation themselves as they have an office here in Berlin and so I was hoping that this might be an issue they've dealt with in the past and would have a standard answer or proof. But thanks for your help!

Comment: By which I mean that the tax office being the tax office it's entirely possible that they won't be happy with anything other than a document that clearly states that X amount of Ether was purchased for Y Euros on DD/YY. But i'm very grateful for your assistance, thank you!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I can "scrape" the transactions for you and output the data to any format. Find me on Twitter (QuickBlocks) and we can discuss.

Comment: Just note that the tax office has to comply with the law, and that the law probably says more "you have to prove that you owned them" than "the tax office has the right to ask you the proof it wants". And it is a lot easier to counterfeit a paper document than a transaction on the blockchain. So if you have any problem with the office, you should consider taking a lawyer's advice - given the value of your ether, it is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your Ether presale file (the JSON file before it was a keystore file) it has the BTC address (labeled as `BtcAddr`) that made the purchase.

Make a copy of your presale file, open it in TextEdit or Notepad++, and there's your Bitcoin address. Then go to a Bitcoin block explorer and you can easily find the transaction for the purchase.

Comment: Is it possible to prove the veracity of the presale file? Especially the BTC address and the email fields.